# restrict access to one page using htaccess in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a page in Wordpress `theme_directory/page-rsvp.php` that i need password protected by .htaccess. I'm developing this locally using MAMP PRO.

I have an .htaccess and .htpasswd file in the theme_directory. I have the following in the .htaccess file but it's not working. Whenever I go to localhost:8888/site/rsvp the authentication prompt doesn't show up.

```
 <Files “page-rsvp.php”>
   AuthName "Username and password required"
   AuthUserFile ./.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
   AuthType Basic
 </Files>
```

There is of course the .htaccess file in the root of the wordpress install that looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /thepowerfulnow/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /thepowerfulnow/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How do I get this to work using only the first .htaccess file (the one in the theme_directory)? I need to have this theme be modular. I'm very new to .htaccess files. Thank you all!

Comment: Have you tried using `"` instead of the non-ascii `”`?

Comment: good catch! i need new glasses :( unfortunately that didn't fix it.

Comment: Even tried removing the quotes but that didn't fix it either. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've added the authentication to your theme directory, so it'll work only if you access your theme file directly, using a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/site/wp-content/themes/theme_directory/page-rsvp.php
```

If you want to restrict the access to your page URL (e.g. `/site/rsvp`), you need to use a different rule. You can add the following lines to the end of your main `.htaccess` file, that in the WordPress root dir.

```
# Set an env variable "auth" if the URI starts with "/site/rsvp"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/site/rsvp auth=1

AuthName "User and password required"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "./.htpasswd"

# First, allow anyone
Order Allow,Deny
Satisfy any
Allow from all
Require valid-user
# Then, deny only if auth is required
Deny from env=auth
```

Remember to keep a copy of `.htpasswd` file into the same directory or set the path to that file using the `AuthUserFile` directive.

### Alternative solution

My original answer used a `<Location>` directive to filter the URL to restrict, but **it do not work in `.htaccess` files**. Only under server config or a virtual host. Check the *Context* here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location

If you want to use the restriction rule as below, and you have access in the server to do so, you need to add it to some of those contexts (server config or virtual host). Apache's config files are usually in the `/etc/httpd` or `/etc/apache2` directories.

```
<Location "/site/rsvp"> # Where /site/rsvp is the URL you want to restrict
    AuthName "Username and password required"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    AuthType Basic
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I've tried both of your solutions and it's not working. I'm very new at .htaccess but my guess is that it could have to do with something in the second .htaccess file i provided in the OP. as it reconfigures the sites permalinks. with your first solution I replaced "site" with the appropriate folder name, ie the site name, and "theme_directory" with the name of the theme and no luck however this did not break my site's css. the second solution I tried a relative path and an absolute path but both broke my site's css. any suggestions please? thank you!!

Comment: Just to confirm, did you tried to add the `<Location>` directive to your main .htaccess?

Comment: if by main you mean the one that's in the theme_directory then yes. I haven't tried this with the one in the root of my wordpress install. Should I?

Comment: Yes. That one in the root of your Wordpress is your main `.htaccess`. Try to add that to the end of your file, in a new line after the comment: `# END WordPress`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your suggestion but it creates a 500 internal server error. I hopefully have the url wrong. The full path to the file I need to restrict is `/applications/mamp/htdocs/thepowerfulnow/wp-content/themes/thepowerfulnow/page-rsvp.php` and the root .htaccess file is in `applications/mamp/htdocs/thepowerfulnow`. the url I provided this .htaccess file is `<Location "/thepowerfulnow/rsvp">` as well as `<Location “./wp-content/themes/thepowerfulnow/rsvp">` but both return the same 500 internal server error. could this be because of MAMP? help appreciated! thank you all!!

Comment: Hey @user2731260, I've updated my answer with the correct solution. Check that.

Comment: Hey, @hot_barbara! Have my updates to the answer ever helped you? If so, please accept/upvote it. This way you can help others seeking a solution for a similar problem.

Comment: Actually I'm no longer working on this project and have no way to test your updated answer unfortunately. Thanks anyway though.